# Transitivity of convergence of sequence in $L^1$ and $BV$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, sequence-of-function

Let $(f_n)_n\in BV([0,T])$ a sequence of functions of bounded variation converging to some $f\in BV([0,T])$, that is to say

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\parallel f_n-f\parallel_{BV([0,T])} = 0.$$
and such that
$$\forall n, f_n(0)=f(0)$$
Let $(g_n)_n\in BV([0,T])$ a sequence of function of bounded variations such that the following holds
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\parallel g_n-f_n\parallel_{L^1([0,T])} = 0$$

Does the following holds ?

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\parallel g_n-f\parallel_{L^1([0,T])}=0$$

If not, is there a topology where some convergence result holds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counter-example:  $f_n(x)=g_n(x)=n$ and $f(x)=0$.

Answer for the edited version: Convefence in BV norm together with $f_n(0)=f(0)=0$ impiies uniform convergence, hence also convergence in $L^{1}$. [$|h(x)-h(0)| \leq \|h\|_{BV}$ if $h(0)=0$].   Hence, the answer is YES.

Comment: $f_n-f$ is  a constant function so $\|f_n-f\|_{BV}=0$ for all $n$. @PoloMali

Comment: Indeed, I need to add that $f_n(0) = f(0)$ $\forall n$

Comment: Where is that stated?

Comment: It was not, I just added it